# Can the timbre of the instrument section of a music completely change the music someone suppose to play?

Tags: acoustics

Can the timbre variable have such influence on a specific "sheet music" for two or more instruments someone would execute, that its actual interpretation could transform it on a another music? I mean, if you synthesize the timbre of the sound wave of each instrument section on a computer, changing it fast enough, can the resultant leading wave frequency be another? For example, can someone change say Beethoven on the Baby Shark melody (or another simple melody) just by adjusting the timbre of the instruments the original sheet music is played? I am thinking if a Fourier series sum of this waves representing the instruments parts, with the fundamental frequency of each wave determined by the "sheet music", could be used to generate for example a simple melody. Is this viable on actual sounds speakers?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more suited to https://music.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this question needs someone who understands Fourier analysis.

Comment: And someone who understands acoustics and music.

Comment: Difficult to find someone in both these categories...

Comment: I would like to know why it has been down rated... What is wrong with what I said?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question was downvoted (not by me) because what you are asking is extremely unclear, and because what it appears you are asking makes very little sense. The melody, or the tune, of a piece of music is determined by the fundamental frequencies of the notes being played. This is completely independent of timbre, which concerns not only the harmonics but also the transients and inharmonic frequencies which some instruments possess. As a mathematician with expertise in Fourier analysis, as well as a (past) career in digital sound processing, I have some expertise, but I still think you will find people with greater knowledge of music on SE Music: Theory and Practice.

Comment: Well, thanks. Now I know what is wrong with my question. It seems to be a language problem about timbre definition. What I learned about timbre is that it is defined by the wave format of a sound and the envelope of it. So the same fundamental frequency can have different wave formats, a perfect sine wave or some irregular pattern, like a saw, or other things. Your definition seems to point the harmonics analysis of the sound. I think these two definition are connected, because a leaned also that the wave format determines the harmonics of a sound (is that right?). (... continue)

Comment: Well but if we just think about the wave of a sound, it could be mathematically be decomposed on a Fourier sum of sine waves. So, in thesis, you could reproduce approximation of a timbre of a instrument on a computer by this process. Well, I understand when you play two instruments at the same time  the air molecules make some kind of Fourier sum of the waves. I understand this is why you could have the destruction phenomena of waves that cancel each other and produce silence.

Comment: Well, now this is my thought process to arrive at this question: if you could do this, you could, in thesis, given a instrument playing, to change the second instrument so that the Fourier sum of the two waves produces another fundamental frequency different of the first instrument.

Comment: But if you could do this, perhaps with a sufficient number of instruments, even with all fundamental frequencies of this instruments determined, to change the fundamental frequency of the first instrument when you sum up all the waves of the instruments.

Comment: In some intuitive way of thinking, I think the question is if there is some way to make a destructive interference of the fundamental frequency, and resonance of the components of the sound wave, such that in the sum of the waves you could change the fundamental frequency of each individual instrument, even if this fundamental frequencies of the instruments were determined before they were played. The fundamental thing, saying in mathematical terms, I think is the question: if  you are given the average of some frequencies of waves, could you change the average of its Fourier sum?

Comment: I know there is a lot of imprecision and errors in what I am saying, I don't expect an answer, just to understand the concepts behind it, I will ask at music, thanks.

Comment: To cancel out the fundamental frequencies, you would have to manipulate the signals so that the fundamental frequencies were antiphase and of the same amplitude. That could probably be done digitally (but not for real instruments), but it would need constant adjustment for every note being played. You would end up with a signal dominated by the harmonics. It would almost certainly sound pretty grim, but would not create a different tune. My best guess is that is would be similar enough to the original, played an octave higher, that someone with a good ear would recognise the original tune.

Comment: Also, as different instruments have different decay rates when a note is played, matching amplitudes would require constant adjustments.

Comment: I think this answer partly my doubts, thanks. I would upvote your comment if i could.